# Create a custom function to validate Data in Google Spreadsheet by App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to make the function like this in google spreadsheet:

- When I choose value of column on "Column 1" then I want in "Column 2" show only the corresponding value with "Column B".
- And after select the value at the "Column 2" then Value of "Column 3" will auto display the corresponding value with "Column C"

For example, if In "Column 1" I choose value "1", in "Column 2" will show only values "11,12,13" .

- If I choose value "11" in "Column 2", in "Column 3" will auto display value "111"
- If I choose value "12" in "Column 2", in "Column 3" will auto display value "121"
- If I choose value "13" in "Column 2", in "Column 3" will auto display value "131"

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please explain what you tried so far and in what context are you using it? This usually tells us what level you have and how to help you the best!

Comment: I'm trying to it with App script .

Comment: https://prnt.sc/14lwklr
this is additional pictures . I'm trying it with function onEdit() on App Script . but i don't know how to change the value of column 2 when selecting the value of column 1 . Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How much JavaScript do you know?

Comment: I'm newbie.  I'm learning App Script

Answer (score 1):

This can be split into 2 independent problems:

1. When setting a value on the E column, add set the proper validations for column F of that row.
2. When setting a value on the F column, automatically set column G of that row.

This is actually quite advanced as it requires quite a bit of knowledge about Apps Script. I'll go step by step but not in code order but more in a "how I would think about it" order. I'm leaving a bunch of references to everything I'll use at the end. If you have any questions, please ask for clarification :)

### Setting values on column G

I'll start with this one as it's slightly simpler than the other.

When editing an spreadsheet you can edit multiple cells in a single action. For example: pasting multiple cell values will only trigger a single `onEdit` but the range defined will be of the modification. Because of that, we can't assume that there is only a single cell and we have to treat it like it's always multiple cells. Because of that, the way of setting the values will be:

1. Get the edited range in the F column (and only the F column)
2. Get the values
3. Map the values to the linked values
4. Get the range to set the values to
5. Set the values

#### Getting the edited range in column F

To start with, let's create a function for this. I'll call it `setColGValues(e)` (feel free to change it).

```js
function setColGValues(e) {
  // Code goes here
}
```

`e` is the event for `onEdit` as it contains information that we'll use to extract the information about the edit.

Now we need to get the affected part of column F. To do so I'll be using a utility function. It will be explained later on. To get it we'll do:

```js
  const range = rangeIntersection(e.range, 'F2:F')
  if (!range) return
```

This will get a rance with all the edited cells in the F column (starting with F2). If there is no such range (for example the edit is in another column), return.

#### Getting the values

Simply call [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). I'll save it to `values`.

This is a 2 dimensional array. It's basically an array for rows, where each row is an array of values. So this table

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

Would have the following equivalent value:

```js
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
]
```

#### Setting the values

When we need to set the values we'll map them using Array's `map`. Because we know that we'll only have a single value per row, we can iterate only the columns and get the only value of each row:

```js
  values.map(([value]) => /* something */)
```

Because the values are always the same, the simplest solution is to create an object which is useful for the mapping. Together with that it's like so:

```js
  const gValues = values.map(([value]) => [mapping[value]])
```

#### Make the value mapping

`mapping` is defined before this line and it's an object that maps both columns. In your example is defined by the range `B3:D` and its value would be the following:

```js
{
  11: 111,
  12: 121,
  13: 131,
  21: 211,
  22: 221,
  23: 231,
  31: 311,
  32: 321,
  33: 331,
}
```

To extract the value of that range we first need to get the sheet it is on

```js
  const sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Your sheet name')
```

`e.source` is the spreadsheet that called the event.

Then get the values from the range.

```js
  sheet.getRange(`B3:D`)
    .getValues()
```

But this values may not be valid. For example there could be a value on a D cell but not having a value on B. Because of that, we need to filter the values to make sure there is one. Note that having a value on the B column but not the D can make sense for your case. In this case we'll use the [`filter` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Again for ease of user I'll use the destructing syntax.

```js
  /*[...]*/
    .filter(([b, _d]) => b)
```

At this point we have an array with pairs of values. We want the first to be the key and the second the value of a new object. Fortunately for us, [`Object.fromEntries` does exactly that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). So everything together:

```js
  const mapping = Object.fromEntries(
    sheet.getRange(`B3:D`)
      .getValues()
      .filter(([b, _d]) => b !== '')
  )
```

#### Setting the values

The first thing we need is the equivalent range for column G for the range for column F that we have. The best way of doing that is creating another range offsetted by one. Range already has a function for this: [`offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset). Then we can call [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) with the mapped values:

```js
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(gValues)
```

### Setting validations for column F

Setting validations of column F based on column E is pretty similar to the previous problem. The differences are:

- The obvious change on columns
- You call [`setDataValidations(rules)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules) instead of `setValues`.
- Working with rules instead of values.
- The generation of the mapping between the E column and the validations.

The main difference is that now for each entry on column A we have multiple values on column B to be attached. The group then need to be converted into a rule and, finally, into an object to map with.

#### Creating rules

There are multiple ways of doing this. I'll leave with one but I'd encourage you to try more, as it's a good exercise to understand how things work.

```js
  const entries = []
  let currentA
  let currentMap
  for (let [a, b] of sheet.getRange('A1:B').getValues()) {
    if (a !== currentA) {
      if (currentMap) {
        entries.push([
          currentA,
          SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(currentMap, true).build()
        ])
      }
      currentA = a
      currentMap = []
    }
  }
  
  const mapping = Object.fromEntries(entries)
```

`SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(values, true).build()` creates a data validation with a list of values and a dropdown. Then we can convert Entries to a mapping.

### Joining them

You may join them by simply calling both individual functions:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  setColFValidation(e)
  setColGValues(e)
}
```

It actually doesn't matter the order so you could order them in the opposite order.

If you have multiple sheets, you need to check that the sheet is the correct one:

```js
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName === 'Your sheet name') {
    // Call the functions
  }
```

### Useful utilities used

```js
function rangeIntersection(a, b) {
  // Allow the second argument to be an A1 notation range
  if (isString(b))
    b = a.getSheet().getRange(b)

  // Compute the bounds
  const top    = Math.max( a.getRow(),        b.getRow()        )
  const bottom = Math.min( a.getLastRow(),    b.getLastRow()    )
  
  const left   = Math.max( a.getColumn(),     b.getColumn()     )
  const right  = Math.min( a.getLastColumn(), b.getLastColumn() )

  // If the bounds don't make a range (ie. the ranges don't intersect)
  if (top >= bottom || left >= right)
    return null

  // Get the range
  return a.getSheet().getRange(top, left, bottom - top, right - left)
}
```

`rangeIntersection` returns the range that is part of both ranges. The second argument is allowed to be a string.

```js
function isString(v) {
  return typeof v === 'string' || v instanceof String
}
```

`isString` returns if the value is a string. Useful because string can be of type `string` or be an object of class `String`.

### References

- [JavaScript spread syntax (...) (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [JavaScript `for ... of` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [`Object.fromEntries()` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.map()` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Edit event object (Apps Script guide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [SpreadsheetApp `newDataValidation()` (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newdatavalidation)
- [Class `DataValidationBuilder` (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [Spreadsheet `getSheetByName(name)` (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [Range `offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)` (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)
- [Range `getValues()` (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Range `setValues(values)` (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Range `setDataValidations(rules)` (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules)

Comment: Hey @chubinh, did this help?